# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name - Struts 2

Tags: struts2

### I am getting this error when using annotation instead of XML in struts 2.

```
@Namespace("/")
@Result(name = "success", location = "/output.jsp")
public class HelloAnno extends ActionSupport{
    private String name;
   @Action(value = "/annoTest")
    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
@RequiredFieldValidator(message = "Required!")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Code of the Action class , please !

Comment: Please edit your OP to accommodate the code in it .

Comment: Please post text, not images.